# Can rust-toolchain.toml be a development environment descriptor

Tags: rust, development-environment, toolchain, rustup

Currently, [rust-toolchain.toml](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html?highlight=toolchain#the-toolchain-file), allows specification of the development channel, target platform, and associated tooling (compiler, packager), etc. Unfortunately, the `components` key which accepts additional tools does not accommodate the stipulation of `cargo-watch` and `trunk` (a cargo alternative for WASM crates). As a newbie, their rejection seems strange. Their exclusion limits the amazing utility of `rust-toolchain.toml` to automate the tooling of a development environment.

The question is, am I missing something? Is there a way to integrate these tools into `rust-toolchain.toml`, is there some other way for them be a specified (apart from a shell script), or are they redundant?

Presently I manually install them: `cargo install watch trunk`. Yes, this is easy and simple but also undocumented, forgettable, and clumsy.

*I must say, `rust` and its tooling is impressive.*

Comment: Do you know of a language platform that does this? It sounds like a generic third-party tool installation step, but the necessary parts of a development environment can be extremely varied: ides, extensions, plugins, scripts, system libraries, credential managers. Perhaps there could be a mechanism to auto-install a list of `cargo install`-able programs, but I doubt it'd go further than that. In my experience, this kind of stuff is still commonly handled via `make` files.

Comment: Visual Studio is fairly comprehensive, actually. The distinction between `rust-toolchain.toml` moderated tools and the other crate available tools seems soft. Such a distinction is ultimately invisible to the developers anyway and and since these tools are in `crates.io` and are installable like the others, perhaps with a notification for security reasons they should be includable. However, I am a newbie and there may be subtle reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the `components` key is specifically for toolchain internal components. These components are also toolchain specific, e.g. a `rustup +stable component add rust-src` is different from a `rustup +nightly component add rust-src`.

On the other hand, crates from crates.io (which is what `cargo install` can install) are essentially toolchain independent. So it makes sense to me that crates in general can not be specified by `rust-toolchain.toml` file, which is more about pinning the toolchain to a specific version.

However, about cargo plugins specifically, maybe you find a compelling way to propose this as new feature to cargo (e.g. allow specifying cargo plugins in `config.toml`).

Answer (score 1):

No, the `components` of a `rust-toolchain.toml` are a [specific set of tools](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/concepts/components.html) developed and distributed by the Rust language team. It is only used to augment the built-in `cargo` commands.

Comment: There is `cargo watch -x check` where `watch` is actually a crate that cannot be specified in `rust-toolchain.toml`. It is rather confusing especially since `watch` seems like an essential augment (and concept) of any tooling.

Comment: I'm aware of `cargo watch` and it is a third-party subcommand. It is not provided by the language team and as such wouldn't be considered in `rust-toolchain.toml`. To call it essential is opinion, I don't use it in any of my workflows.